# Setting up Automapper 5.1

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, automapper-5

I am having trouble following the wiki in this instance.  I wanted to use Automapper 5.2. I cannot find a simple end for end example that shows a solid configuration with context. By context I mean where do you put the config files and whats the difference between static and instance api?

I checked out the DNRTV download but it deals with the 1.0 version.

How do you set this package up?  I have a model called Client as below.

```
    public class Client : IEntityBase
{
    public Client()
    {
        Jobs = new List<Job>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientNo { get; set; }
    public bool Company { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ClientFirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeActivated { get; set; }
    public bool Activity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

    public int? StateId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

and a ClientViewModel as so:

```
    public class ClientViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientNo { get; set; }
    public bool Company { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ClientFirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeActivated { get; set; }
    public bool Activity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public int? StateId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public int[] Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

I am unsure how to set AutoMapper up with regard to configuration. That is, they talk about a global.asax file and I am using aspnet core.. there is no Global.asax file..

What do you put in the Startup.cs file if anything.

Given these two files above what do I need to do to use Automapper with them?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the steps to configure the automapper in asp.net core mvc.

**1.** Create the mapping profile class which extends from `Profile`

```
 public class ClientMappingProfile : Profile
 {
     public ClientMappingProfile ()
     {
         CreateMap<Client, ClientViewModel>().ReverseMap();
     }
 }
```

**2.** Create the AutoMapper Configuration Class and add your mapping profile class here.

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
   public MapperConfiguration Configure()
   {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<ClientMappingProfile>();
        });
        return config;
    }
}
```

**3.** Create extension method so, we can add this to `Startup.cs ConfigureServices` method

```
public static class CustomMvcServiceCollectionExtensions
{
   public static void AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
   {
       if (services == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
       }
       var config = new AutoMapperConfiguration().Configure();
       services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => config.CreateMapper());
    }
}
```

**4.** Call the extension method in `Startup.cs ConfigureServices` method

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
     services.AddMvc();

     services.AddAutoMapper();
}
```

Comment: Something concrete.. thankyou very much.. will up vote this!... I do have a question.. what does ".ReverseMap()" do?

Comment: It did bi-directional mapping like in above example Client to ClientViewModel and ClientViewModel to Client

Comment: FYI the AutoMapper project does all this for you automatically: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection