# Mapper not initialized , error with my unit test Core.Net 2.0

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, automapper

I have a WebApi done in Core.net 2.0, with UOW , and automapper.
Everything is working fine, but now I want to implement Unit Test with Nunit, and I have this error of automapper

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Mapper not initialized.
>   Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to
>   use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you
>   do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're
>   using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you
>   pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

How can I solve this. Thanks in advance .
Jolynice

Class AutoMapperProfile.cs

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Cars, CarsDTO>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

class Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        //removed configurations 

        // Add cors
        services.AddCors();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
        });

        // Repositories
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, HttpUnitOfWork>();
        services.AddScoped<IAccountManager, AccountManager>();
    }
}
```

class carsController.cs

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CarsController : Controller
{
private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly IAccountManager _accountManager;

public CarsController(
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
    ILogger<CarsController> logger, 
    IAccountManager accountManager)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _logger = logger;
    _accountManager = accountManager;
}


[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var allCars = _unitOfWork.CarsRepository.GetAllCarsData();
    if (allCars == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CarsDTO>>(allCars));
}
```

and this is my unit test

```
[TestFixture]
public class CarsControllerTest
{
#region private variables
List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>();

CarsController _carsController = null;
IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
ICarsRepository _carsRepository;
#endregion


[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    cars = new List<Cars>
    {
     new Cars
    {
        Alias = "406Moq",
        BrandId = 1,
        ModelId = 1,
        Plate = "00-00-01",
        AltranVehicle = 0,
        DefaultCar = 0,
        Active = 1,
        ColorId = 1
    }
    };
}


[Test]
public void GetAllCarsControllerTest()
{
    //Arrange
    _carsRepository = SetupCarsRepository();
    var unityOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    var _logger = new Mock<ILogger<CarsController>>();
    var accountManager = new Mock<IAccountManager>();

    unityOfWork.SetupGet(c => c.CarsRepository).Returns(_carsRepository);
    _unitOfWork = unityOfWork.Object;

    _carsController = new CarsController(_unitOfWork, _logger.Object, accountManager.Object);


    //Act
    var carsResult = _carsController.GetAll();

    //Assert
    carsResult.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

private ICarsRepository SetupCarsRepository()
{
    //initialize  repository
    var mockRepo = new Mock<ICarsRepository>(MockBehavior.Default);

    //Setup mocking behavior
    mockRepo.Setup(c => c.GetAllCarsData()).Returns(cars);

    return mockRepo.Object;
}

//Cleanup
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    cars = null;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Mapper.Initialize` for dotnet core 2.0 there's `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup))`. Our profile classes inherit from `MapperConfigurationExpression`.

Comment: Hello Boggin, I will try It. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper error saying mapper not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284349/automapper-error-saying-mapper-not-initialized)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are missing initialization of your mapper in your unit test. The following initializes the mapper in the `CarsControllerTest` class constructor.

```
[TestFixture]
public class CarsControllerTest
{
    public CarsControllerTest()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks CK R, that´s rigth, I forgot, that and now is working fine. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Ups, sorry CK, click mouse.Done ;)

Comment: No worries, Thanks