# How do I manually register AutoMapper profiles, in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using ASP.NET Core, with the built-in container.

Automatic registration is done [like so](http://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.AddProfiles(typeof(Startup)));
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(s => config.CreateMapper());
```

This automatically 1) configures AutoMapper, and 2) registers all profiles found in the assembly.

But I want to register my profiles manually. How do I do that?

Comment: check this one how to configure automapper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220742/setting-up-automapper-5-1/41221647#41221647

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the **sigular** version of the method.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => {
    c.AddProfile<ProfileA>();
    c.AddProfile<ProfileB>();
});
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(s => config.CreateMapper());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new AutoMapper.MapperCOnfiguration and instead of call AddProfiles you can use the CreateMap method for each profile you want register.
Something like this

```
var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<myObj, myObjDto>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Then just inject mapper and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I utilise **Autofac** for my ASP.NET Core project - here's how my code looks:

(below is the declaration of Autofac module)

```
public class DefaultModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfileConfiguration()));
        var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        builder.Register(c => mapper).As<IMapper>().SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

`SingleInstance()` is the equivalent of `AddSingleton()`.

**AutoMapper profile:**

```
public class AutoMapperProfileConfiguration : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfileConfiguration()
    {
        CreateMap<TeamDto, Team>();
    }
}
```

And here's how we register services:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule<DefaultModule>();
    containerBuilder.Populate(services);
    var container = containerBuilder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```