# Type is not valid in the given context, automapper .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I am using AutoMapper in my ASP.NET Core project. When I want to map from DTO type into model type I am getting error:

> "Type is not valid in the given context".

This is my mapper configuration:

```
protected AutoMapperOrderConfiguration(string profileName) : base(profileName)
{
    CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>();
    CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>();
}
```

Here is the code that produces the error:

```
public void Add(OrderDTO item)
{
    var model = _mapper.Map(OrderDTO, Order)(item);
    _orderRepository.Add(model);
}
```

Here I want to add new DTO item and then I want to transform it to base model. Then I get error.

```
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] OrderDTO item)
{
    if (item.OrderType == "" || item.ServiceType=="")
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _orderDTORepository.Add(item);
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetOrder", new { id = item.OrderId }, item);
}
```

Comment: please check this how to configurations auto mapper  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220742/setting-up-automapper-5-1/41221647#41221647

Comment: my mapper works, i could map from Model to DTOModel. Reverse, i cant.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the mapping call be:

```
_mapper.Map<Order>(item);
```

Now we define that we wish to map `item` to the `Order` class.

Comment: oh i used ( instead of <>

Comment: That, and you don't need to define what type you are mapping from since it can figure that out from the object you pass in.