# Trying to add AutoMapper to .NetCore1.1 - not recognising services.AddAutoMapper()

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper, .net-core

I've installed the following Nuget packages into my project:

- `Automapper`
- `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

I have added the line to `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    // . . .
    services.AddAutoMapper();
}
```

I'm still getting a red line under `services.AddAutoMapper()`. It says:

> The Call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection, params Assembly[]) and ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection, params Type[])

Why is this happening? All the .NET Core add automapper guides I've read show to do it this way.

Comment: What version of the .NET Core SDK are you using?

Comment: `dotnet --version` says `1.0.0`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are using project.json. Is that right?

Comment: `appsettings.json`

Comment: Do you have a project.json or a csproj file?

Comment: I have the csproj

Comment: I tried targetting `.Net Core 1.0` and still came up the error. I'm originally targetting `1.1 `

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220742/setting-up-automapper-5-1/41221647#41221647

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure why this is happening, it could very well be something to do with `.NET Core 1.1` but I have found a workaround.

Instead of doing `services.AddAutoMapper()` in `ConfigureServices`, replace it with the below.

```
var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            });

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Where `MappingProfile()` is the class in which you have your `CreateMap`.

Answer (score 62):

I just ran into this problem and came to know that 
You need to include following Nuget package **AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.Dependencyinjection**

Comment: The question states that they have already included this Nuget package.

Answer (score 27):

I'm running into the same issue, so checked the [sourcecode and tests](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/TestApp/Program.cs) for guidance. It seems you need to pass either an assembly or a "marker type" inside the assembly you want scanned. I went for the following as my `Profile` classes are in the same assembly as the `Startup` class.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

Comment: What do you add if your profile classes are not in the same assembly ?

Comment: `typeof(ATypeInTargetAssembly)`

Comment: Yep, that's what I did in the end and it worked... I found you can also add a list of these, thus allowing for multiple dependencies being configured. Might be helpful for others reading these comments to know this.

Comment: As Ikram Shah's answer points out... adding the nuget pkg `automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection` is the answer to resolving extension method `AddAutoMapper()` when configuring services in `Startup.cs` like `services.AddAutoMapper();`

Comment: You can use something like this: services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMappingProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

Answer (score 6):

Search this in nuget you can access automap

```
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

Answer (score 3):

**Install package:**

```
Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection -Version 7.0.0
```

**Nuget:** 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To solved this issue I used the following versions of AutoMapper in project.csproj:

```
AutoMapper Version="6.0.1"
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection Version="1.2.0"
```

Restore all packages and finally close and open the visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (in .NET Core 2.2, Visual Studio Code 1.34.0, Ubuntu OS) despite having installed **AutoMapper** package (v8.1.0) and the **AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.Dependencyinjection** package (v6.1.0).

The problem was solved by changing version of the packages in project.csproj as follows:

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0"/>
```

Somehow it looks like due to the package version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, the solution was a combination of the answers above:

1. download the Nuget Package for Automapper -> **Automapper** by Jimmy
   Bogard
2. download the Nuget Package for the Automapper Dependency Injection -> **AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection**  by Jimmy
   Bogard
3. add `using Automapper;` in the Startup.cs file

Now `service.AddAutoMapper` should work correctly. You can now initialize the Automapper to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Add Nuget package for automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection
Latest Stable version 9

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is add ***using AutoMapper;*** at the top of **Startup.cs** file. Best of Luck!!!!